# TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined - ReactJS - Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, enzyme

I'm writing tests for the render section on the container, whether the button is properly rendered. Below is the code is have used

```
it('should render translation inputs', () => {
            const wrapper = shallow(<COAForwardTranslations store ={storeData}/>)
            expect(wrapper.find('.btn-primary').length).toBe(1);

      });
```

I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined", Can you please help me, i have reinstalled

```
npm install --save-dev jest
npm install --save-dev babel-jest regenerator-runtime
```

but i still get the error.

What am i doing wrong to just check if the the button is rendered properly on the container.

```
class COAForwardTranslations extends Component
{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
                SegmentMapRequest : {
                BranchCode: '',
                GroupId: '',
                GlCompanyCode: '',
                GlAccount: '',
                SourceMode: '',
                SourceSystem: '',
                JournalCategory: '',
                EffectiveDate: ''
            },
            segmentMapResponse:{}
        }
        this.handleRequestChange = this.handleRequestChange.bind(this);
        this.handleForwardTranslation = this.handleForwardTranslation.bind(this);
        this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
    }

    handleRequestChange(e){
        let inputName = e.target.name;
        let inputValue = e.target.value;
        let requestCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.SegmentMapRequest);
        requestCopy[inputName] = inputValue;
        this.setState({SegmentMapRequest: requestCopy});
    }
    handleForwardTranslation(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.getForwardTranslation(this.state.SegmentMapRequest);
    }
handleReset()
    {
        this.setState({SegmentMapRequest: {
            BranchCode: '',
                GroupId: '',
                GlCompanyCode: '',
                GlAccount: '',
                SourceMode: '',
                SourceSystem: '',
                JournalCategory: '',
                EffectiveDate: ''
            },
            segmentMapResponse : {}
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where `.bind` is being used?

Comment: i have added the code.should have included before.

Comment: You don't have `handleReset` function in the class. Thats why its complaining about it. Remove `this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this); ` from the constructor or introduce a `handleReset` function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with

```
this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
```

`this.handleReset` is not present in your code, so when you try to call `.bind()` on it, it throws that error.